# GCP - gcloud commands history for actions done via GUI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When I do something in GCP console (by clicking in GUI), I imagine some `gcloud` command is executed underneath. Is it possible to view this command?

(I created a notebooks instance on Vertex AI and wanted to know what exactly I should put after `gcloud notebooks instances create...` to get the same result)

Comment: The GCP Console GUI does not execute `gcloud` CLI commands. The GUI uses REST APIs. You can see the APIs that the GUI calls by opening the browser debugger and going to the Network tab. Reverse engineering that into CLI commands is challenging and an interesting learning exercise. However, you should know the REST APIs first to understand what you are viewing.

Comment: Rather than a comment on the question this should have been an answer, and it would have been the correct one.

Comment: Exactly, thanks @JohnHanley for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to view a `gcloud` command from GUI.
You should test your `gcloud` command to create another instance alongside the current with all the needed parameters.
When the 2 instances are the same, you know that your `gcloud` command is ready.

The documentation seems to be clear and complete for this :

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/create-new#gcloud

If it's possible for you, you can also think about `Terraform` to automate this creation for you with a state management.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a Python based User Managed Notebook (GUI version of Python instance is using the base image as boot disk, which does not containg Pythong.
The Python suite is installed explicitly via Metadata parameters):

```
export NETWORK_URI="NETWORK URI"
export SUBNET_URI="SUBNET URI"
export INSTANCE_NAME="instance-name-of-your-liking"
export VM_IMAGE_PROJECT="deeplearning-platform-release"
export VM_IMAGE_FAMILY="common-cpu-notebooks-debian-10"
export MACHINE_TYPE="n1-standard-4"
export LOCATION="europe-west3-b"
gcloud notebooks instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
--no-public-ip \
--vm-image-project=$VM_IMAGE_PROJECT \
--vm-image-family=$VM_IMAGE_FAMILY \
--machine-type=$MACHINE_TYPE \
--location=$LOCATION \
--network=$NETWORK_URI \
--subnet=$SUBNET_URI \
--metadata=framework=NumPy/SciPy/scikit-learn,report-system-health=true,proxy-mode=service_account,shutdown-script=/opt/deeplearning/bin/shutdown_script.sh,notebooks-api=PROD,enable-guest-attributes=TRUE
```

To get a list of Network URIs in your project:

```
gcloud compute networks list --uri
```

To get a list of Subnet URIs in your project:

```
gcloud compute networks subnets list --uri
```

Put the corresponding URIs in between the quotation marks in the first two variables:

```
export NETWORK_URI="NETWORK URI"
export SUBNET_URI="SUBNET URI"
```

Name the instance (keep the quotation marks):

```
export INSTANCE_NAME="instance-name-of-your-liking"
```

When done copy paste the complete block in your Google Cloud Shell (assuming you are in a correct project).

To additionally enable secure boot (which is a thick box in the GUI setup):

```
gcloud compute instances stop $INSTANCE_NAME

gcloud compute instances update $INSTANCE_NAME --shielded-secure-boot
```

Hope it works for you, as it does for me.